# Present View Controller and Add Child View Controller Cause App Freeze

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I have `AViewController`. Inside `A`, I have a `MapViewController` instance. `MapViewController` is `A`'s Child View Controller.

Now when a button inside `A` got `TouchUpInside`, I init a `BViewController`. and present `B`.

When init `BViewController` I pass in the `MapViewController` to `B` and stored inside `B` as an unowned variable.

I need to display the same map for both `A` and `B`. Inside `B`'s `viewDidLoad`, I add `MapViewController` as Child View Controller for `B`.

The app freezes when I press the button. No exception, No crash, No error log.

Anyone have any ideas why it happens?

---

#### My Attempts:

1. I tried to use a navigation controller and use pushViewController methods, same result, app freezes
2. I tried to add `MapViewController` as child inside `B` at `ViewWillAppear`, same result, app freezes
3. I tried to add `MapViewController` as child inside `B` at `ViewDidAppear`, no more freeze, but map is not there at all.
4. Instead of present `B` I tried to add `B` as childViewController of `A`, same result, app freezes
5. I checked all the instructions on running on main threads.
6. I tried to remove `mapViewController` as child in `A` before present `B`, same result, app freezes.
7. I tried to add `mapViewController` as child in completion block when present `B`, same result, app freezes

Comment: Did you try to push B viewController instead ?

Comment: Do you really need to present a new VC? If you want to display the same "Map" in `B`, maybe it would work better if you simply *change* the elements in `A` instead of loading a whole new ViewController.

Comment: @ArthurSahakyan Yes, I did. Same result, app freezes.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the advise. That definitely is a solution. But I do want to understand why this problem happens. Using `B` also makes codes into small modules and make codes more readable. Present `B` also gives user an idea that they are using a new functionality.

Comment: OK - have you stepped through in  Debug to find out *when* the app is freezing?

Comment: When you say you *"need to display the same map for both `A` and `B`"* ... Are you trying to actually ***move*** the `MapViewController` instance from `A` to `B`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes. That's what I am trying to do. I did try remove map from `A` before add to `B`

Comment: OK - that's going to give you plenty of problems. Why not just get the current map properties and instantiate a new instance of `MapViewController` inside `B` with those properties?

Comment: @DonMag lol. The map has custom drawings on it. Init a new `MapViewController` instance will not have those custom drawings anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148916/discussion-between-donmag-and-nuynait).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a better structure to take. When you switch from `A` content to `B` content, you can move / size the elements all you want... And since they will be separate subviews of your "main" view, they can overlap if your interface would benefit from that layout:

[image]